# Switching desktops using hotkey keeps the current application opened

Tags: lxde, desktop

I created multiple desktops using "Openbox Configuration Manager". I see them at the top of the panel and can shift between them normally using the mouse.
However, when I tried to create hotkey configuration in `"/home/pi/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml"` to:

```
 <keybind key="C-Left">
      <action name="SendToDesktopLeft">
        <dialog>no</dialog>
        <wrap>no</wrap>
      </action>
    </keybind>
```

The hotkey does change the desktop, but it keeps the currently opened application opened.

So that, imagine there are 3 applications - 2 terminals and chromium browser. First terminal is active. I change the desktop. Background terminal and chromium browser disappear, but the active terminal is still present.
How can I fix it - so that ALL the windows disappear when I change desktop using the hotkey?

Let me note, the whole reason I am doing is - is because the standard hotkey for switching desktops "Ctrl+Alt+Left" did not do anything. Also, I am using almost new/vanilla Raspberry Pi 3. Debian Version is 9.3. Lxde version is:

```
lxde:
  Installed: 9+rpi1
  Candidate: 9+rpi1
  Version table:
 *** 9+rpi1 500
        500 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/ui armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     9 500
        500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf Packages
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you want [`GoToDesktop`](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions#GoToDesktop) instead:

```xml
<keybind key="C-Left">
  <action name="GoToDesktop">
    <to>left</to>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="C-Right">
  <action name="GoToDesktop">
    <to>right</to>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

This will switch between desktops, rather than moving a window between desktops, which is the purpose of [`SendToDesktop`](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions#SendToDesktop).

Note that the options for `GoToDesktop` are as follows:

> - `<to>`
>
>   - Default:  current
>   - The desktop to switch to, starting from 1, or one of the following special values: "current", "next", "previous", "last", "north" or "up", "south" or "down", "west" or "left", "east" or "right".
> - `<wrap>`
>
>   - Default: yes
>   - A boolean (yes/no) which when enabled lets you wrap around from the last desktop to the first, west to east, north to south, etc, and vice versa.